# condition_variable::wait_for method not returning - even after the timeout

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I come from C# coding experience; I am beginning to learn C++ and make use of boost libraries for threading.
I wrote the following class - trying to execute a member function as a thread. Writing the following simple code, i would expect the while loop inside the thread function to execute every second.

```
#include <boost/chrono/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

class MyClassWithThread : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<MyClassWithThread>
{ 
    mutex                           muThreadControl;
    condition_variable              cvThreadControl;
    bool                            threadToBeStopped = false; 

    void ThreadFunction()
    {
        std::cout << "Beginning the Thread" << std::endl;

        while(true)
        {
            bool endIOThread = false;
            std::cout << "\nChecking if Thread to be stopped: ";
            {
                boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(muThreadControl);
                endIOThread = cvThreadControl.wait_for(lock, 
                    boost::chrono::seconds(1),
                    [this]{return threadToBeStopped;} ) == cv_status::no_timeout;
                std::cout << endIOThread << std::endl
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Exiting the Thread" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    thread                          threadRunner; 
    MyClassWithThread()
    { 
        threadRunner = thread(&MyClassWithThread::ThreadFunction, this);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClassWithThread myclassWithThread;
    myclassWithThread.threadRunner.join();
    return 0;
}
```

To build on Linux:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread cond-wait-test.cpp -o cond-wait-test -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono
```

However, when i execute the code, all i notice is that the thread execution is blocked at the call to wait_for method; forever. despite the timeout period. Further, the resource monitor of the system shows a processor core is being 100% utilized.

Could anyone please explain whats happening in the code?

Comment: There doesn't look to be anything that exits your while loop.

Comment: If it is using 100% CPU then it isn't blocked. Something must be wrong with the predicate check or with the timeout.

Comment: @MohamadElghawi, the code above is for testing purpose; in which i expect the console to print:
Checking if Thread to be stopped: 0
Checking if Thread to be stopped: 0
Checking if Thread to be stopped: 0... <every second>

Comment: @ZanLynx, 100% CPU utilization is not a expected sign because i expect it to just wait for a second (sleeping). Which should not consume any CPU at all..

Comment: @rat6: Since it works for me perhaps you need to include details of your compiler, operating system and Boost version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Zan Lynx, the culprit was #pragma pack statement. I initially used only #pragma pack(1) to byte align some structures. This affected many of mutex structures to 1 byte alignment.

I changed the #pragma pack(1) statements to #pragma pack(push, 1)  #pragma pack(pop). Its all working fine. Hence my problem is solved; i learnt something. Thanks a Lot. ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your program will never exit your while loop.

**Solution.**

Add some kind of termination condition.

```
bool endIOThread = false;
while(!endIOThread)
{
    std::cout << "\nChecking if Thread to be stopped: ";
    {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(muThreadControl);
        endIOThread = cvThreadControl.wait_for(lock, 
            boost::chrono::seconds(1),
            [this]{return threadToBeStopped;} ) == cv_status::no_timeout;
        std::cout << endIOThread << std::endl
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that he wants an infinite loop for testing purposes which should print "Checking..." once per second. In this test the condition should never become true.

Comment: the code above is for testing purpose; in which i expect the console to print:
Checking if Thread to be stopped: 0
Checking if Thread to be stopped: 0
Checking if Thread to be stopped: 0... <every second>

Comment: I know that the condition will never be true and the thread function will never actually FINISH.

But i wonder why is it not printing the "Checking if Thread to be stopped" messages every second?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and tried it on Linux.

Your code as posted will not compile. I wonder if you tried it?

The problem is that `wait_for` with the predicate overload returns a `bool` not a `cv_status`. The inner loop times out, calls the predicate and returns.

Your code works as expected if I remove the predicate lambda. It also works if I leave the lambda and remove the `==` comparison with the `cv_status`.

Perhaps if you do what I did and remove the `using namespace boost;` line and then make all Boost objects explicit.

Here is my modified version which works for me:

```
#include <boost/chrono/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class MyClassWithThread : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<MyClassWithThread>
{
    boost::mutex                           muThreadControl;
    boost::condition_variable              cvThreadControl;
    bool                            threadToBeStopped = false;

    void ThreadFunction()
    {
        std::cout << "Beginning the Thread" << std::endl;

        while(true)
        {
            bool endIOThread = false;
            std::cout << "\nChecking if Thread to be stopped: ";
            {
                boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(muThreadControl);
#if 1
                endIOThread = cvThreadControl.wait_for(lock,
                    boost::chrono::seconds(1),
                    [this]{return threadToBeStopped;} );
#else
                endIOThread = cvThreadControl.wait_for(lock,
                    boost::chrono::seconds(1)) == boost::cv_status::no_timeout;
                std::cout << endIOThread << std::endl;
#endif
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Exiting the Thread" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    boost::thread                          threadRunner;
    MyClassWithThread()
    {
        threadRunner = boost::thread(&MyClassWithThread::ThreadFunction, this);
    }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClassWithThread myclassWithThread;
    myclassWithThread.threadRunner.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Linux GCC build command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread cond-wait-test.cpp -o cond-wait-test -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
You are right; While posting this question, I modified the code around checking the return type of wait_for.

I removed the using declarations and explicitly declared variables with boost::***. But I still do not see the "Checking.." messages printed.

Comment: Hi @Zan, I see that the the file as its listed in the source works fine. However, when I included more header files, it started behaving the same I stated initially. I am more than confused to see this behavior - how merely including few header file can affect this way?

Comment: @rat6: If behavior changes when you include more header files I would first remove all `using namespace` lines. It is possible that a new header introduces a named function that overrides the one you think you are calling with something different. Next, read all the documentation on the headers/libraries you are calling, because it is possible the new header is redefining preprocesser values or enabling alternate features you didn't expect.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. After a good amount of trial and error, i hit a point where i realize one of 'my' source code file contains a struct defined with #pragma pack(1).

When i remove the #pragma pack statement, the program works perfectly as expected. But once the statement - pragma pack(1) is enabled, the wait_for method of condition_variable stalls forever. I however need to define the struct element packing; cant avoid it.

Could you please help by explaining what is happening?

Comment: @rat6 sounds like you packed all the mutex structure definitions. Use pack push and pack pop. Pop will set the packing back to previous.

Comment: Your guess was absolutely correct. I changed the #pragma pack(1) statements to #pragma pack(push, 1) ----- #pragma pack(pop). Its all working fine. 
Hence my problem is solved; i learnt something.

Thanks a Lot. ! :-)
Cheers.